# C++11 field of rvalue is a rvalue

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I'm trying to setup a template to swap arrays in order to be used in move constructors for many classes:

```
template <class T> void tools_swap_array(T* & a, T* & b) noexcept
{
    auto tmp(a);
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

now I want to use it in move constructor and move assignment operators through a common method called move_from():

```
void label::move_from(label && ref) noexcept  
{
    tools_swap_array((char *)val, (char*)ref.val);
}
```

where val is a field of class label:

```
class label
{
public:
    // [...]
    label(label && ref) { move_from(std::move(ref)); };
    label & operator = (label && ref) { move_from(std::move(ref)); return *this; };
    // [...]
private:
    char val[LABEL_SIZE];
};
```

But when I run the compiler, it fails in move_from() telling that **ref.val is an rvalue**!

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char*&'
from an rvalue of type 'char*'  
tools_swap_array((char *)val, (char*)ref.val);
                                            ^
```

I thought that "label && ref" would be an lvalue inside move_from() and so would be "ref.val". So, do I still misunderstand C++11 reference to rvalue or is this a compiler bug?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Casting with `(char *)val` produces an [rvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue) (temporary object) of type `char*` that points to the same address as `val`. Non-const references can't refer to rvalues. The compiler is saying `(char*)ref.val` is an rvalue, not `ref.val`.

Comment: Aside from all the rest, swapping two pointers to the start of arrays of arbitrary size does not modify said arrays at all.

Comment: Stop using raw pointers when programming in c++. These are reserved for rare exceptional cases, which are most probably already solved with facilities from the c++ standard library.

Comment: @user0042 There is nothing wrong with using raw pointers per se. What you should avoid is the use of raw pointers in cases of ownership. See also R.3 of the Cpp Core Guidelines.

Comment: I understand the std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr, but this is old code (C++98) I'm updating a little to C++14 mainly to leverage as much as possible the move scemantics ... but I will not rewrite it all :)

Comment: Thanks to all for the clarifications you brought. I'm surprised that casting a variable produces a rvalue I thought it would just explicitely tell the compiler to assume the variable to stay a lvalue but of the casted type... still strange to me. Now I guess the best thing to do is using std::swap() as Remy mentionned. Thanks!

Comment: @SergeLamartine: Prior to C++11, there was the `std::auto_ptr` smart pointer for automating `delete`.  It was replaced with `std::unique_ptr` in C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to implement this is to not write your own swap function at all.  [`std::swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) has an overload for fixed-sized arrays in C++11 and later, use that instead, eg:

```
#include <utility>

void label::move_from(label && ref) noexcept  
{
    std::swap(val, ref.val);
}
```

If you really want to implement an array swapping function manually, you need to pass references to the actual arrays, instead of passing pointers to them (swapping just the pointers does not swap the array elements at all), eg:

```
#include <algorithm>

template <class T, std::size_t N>
void tools_swap_array(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N]) noexcept
{
    T tmp[N];
    std::copy_n(a, N, tmp);
    std::copy_n(b, N, a);
    std::copy_n(tmp, N, b);
}
```

Or:

```
#include <utility>

template <class T, std::size_t N>
void tools_swap_array(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N]) noexcept
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        std::swap(a[i], b[i]);
}
```

Or (this is essentially what `std::swap()` does):

```
#include <algorithm>

template <class T, std::size_t N>
void tools_swap_array(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N]) noexcept
{
    std::swap_ranges(a, a+N, b);
}
```

Either way, then you can do this:

```
void label::move_from(label && ref) noexcept  
{
    tools_swap_array(val, ref.val);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Remy. I initially tried to setup my own swap template without the size argument as you did (having `T (&a) []` as argument), but it does not work, obviously. so I tried using pointers and got this rvalue error, which surprised me. But you are right, there is no need to define my own swap method, I will use the std::swap one, thanks for pointing me to it and thanks for having detailed the reasons and way I could implement my own swap template :)